# how to get values using foreach

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to create menu dynamically according to the user input. I have an array like this, I want to get each value by their indices or I want to use the values to create menu by their order:

```
$menu['main_menu']= array(
  'menu_name' =>'main_menu',
  'menu_item1'=>array('home' => array('URL' => 'Http://www.google.com','Class name'=>"item_class",'menu_id'=>'new_menu' )),
  'menu_item2'=>array('development' => array('URL' => 'Http://www.google.com','Class name'=>"item_class",'sub_menu'=>'0' )),
  'menu_item3'=>array('php' => array('URL' => 'Http://www.google.com','Class name'=>"item_class",'sub_menu'=>'development' )),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$menu['main_menu']= array(
  'menu_name' =>'main_menu',
  'menu_item1'=>array('home' => array('URL' => 'Http://www.google.com','Class name'=>"item_class",'menu_id'=>'new_menu' )),
  'menu_item2'=>array('development' => array('URL' => 'Http://www.google.com','Class name'=>"item_class",'sub_menu'=>'0' )),
  'menu_item3'=>array('php' => array('URL' => 'Http://www.google.com','Class name'=>"item_class",'sub_menu'=>'development' )),
  'menu_item4'=>array('php2' => array('URL' => 'Http://www.google.com','Class name'=>"item_class",'sub_menu'=>'development' )),
  'menu_item5'=>array('development2' => array('URL' => 'Http://www.google.com','Class name'=>"item_class",'sub_menu'=>'0' )),
  'menu_item6'=>array('php2' => array('URL' => 'Http://www.google.com','Class name'=>"item_class",'sub_menu'=>'development2' )),
);

$submenus = [];
$mainMenu = [];
$menuStart;
$menuEnd;

//prapring data
foreach($menu['main_menu'] as $item){
    if(is_array($item)){
        foreach($item as $link){
            if(isset($link['sub_menu']) & $link['sub_menu'] != '0'){
                $submenus[] = [
                    'name' => key($item),
                    'sub_menu' => $link["sub_menu"],
                    'body' => "<li class='{$link["Class name"]}'><a href='{$link["URL"]}' class='{$link["Class name"]}' id='{$link["menu_id"]}'>" . key($item) . "</a>",
                    'end' => "</li>"
                        ];
            } else {
                $mainMenu[] = [
                    'name' =>  key($item), 
                    'body' => "<li class='{$link["Class name"]}'><a href='{$link["URL"]}' class='{$link["Class name"]}' id='{$link["menu_id"]}'>" . key($item) . "</a>",
                    'end' => "</li>"
                        ];
            }
        }
    } else {
    $menuStart = "<ul class='{$item}'>";
    }
}

/// menu generatig
$menuEnd = '</ul>';
echo $menuStart;
foreach($mainMenu as $menu){
    echo $menu['body'];
        foreach($submenus as $submenu){
            if($submenu["sub_menu"] == $menu['name']){
                echo "<ul>";
                echo $submenu['body'];
                echo "</ul>";
            }    
        }
    echo $menu['end'];
}
echo $menuEnd;
```

Comment: Thank you sir.Actually  i need an output like <ul class="main-menu">
  <li  class="item_class"><a href="Http://www.google.com" id="new_menu"> Home</a></li>
  <li class="item_class"> <a  href="#" id="new_devolp">development</a>
    <ul>

    <li class="item_class"> <a  href="Http://www.google.com" id="something"</a></li>

    </ul>

Comment: yes.this is closer but i want to check whether it comes under any submenu .Here php comes under development so how to create menu like that way

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```
foreach ($menu['main_menu'] as $item => $menu_item) {
    if (is_array($menu_item)) {
        foreach ($menu_item as $menu_name => $menu_attr) {
            echo "menu name: " . $menu_name;
            echo '<br/>';
            foreach ($menu_attr as $attr => $val) {
                echo $attr . "->" . $val;
                echo '<br/>';
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        echo $item.": ".$menu_item;
        echo "<br />";  
    }
}
```

Comment: This is more closer .but i need the first index value of  array also.menu_name->main_menu that is missing here.how to get that also.thank you

Answer (score 1):

Following code may help you.

```
 $menu['main_menu']= array(
      'menu_name' =>'main_menu',
      'menu_item1'=>array('home' => array('URL' => 'Http://www.google.com','Class name'=>"item_class",'menu_id'=>'new_menu' )),
      'menu_item2'=>array('development' => array('URL' => 'Http://www.google.com','Class name'=>"item_class",'sub_menu'=>'0' )),
      'menu_item3'=>array('php' => array('URL' => 'Http://www.google.com','Class name'=>"item_class",'sub_menu'=>'development' )),
    );



    foreach($menu['main_menu'] as $menu_name=>$menu_value){

      echo "<br><br>menu_name ". $menu_name;

      if(is_array ( $menu_value )){

            foreach($menu_value as $k=>$v){
               if(is_array ( $v )){
                   foreach($v as $key=>$value)
                            echo "<br>key=".$key."  value=".$value;

              }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you .this code works but i need the menu_name for setting my menu name and first value of menu_items array too.

Answer (score 1):

truy this

```
foreach($menu['main_menu'] as $menu_name=>$menu_value)
{
  if(is_array($menu_value))
  {
     foreach($menu_value as $value)
     {
      if(is_array ( $value ))
      {
            echo "<a href='{$value["URL"]}' class='{$value["Classname"]}'>" . key($menu_value) . "</a><br />"; // 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: :Actually i need an output like this     <ul class="main-menu"> <li class="item_class"><a href="Http://www.google.com"; id="new_menu"> Home</a></li> <li class="item_class"> <a href="#" id="new_devolp">development</a> <ul> <li class="item_class"> <a href="Http://www.google.com"; id="something"</a></li> </ul>